# XSLT Outer Bracket Node Inside Inner Bracket

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<Root>
    <PersonSettings>
        <Type Drinks="1">A</Type>
        <Type Drinks="2">B</Type>
        <Type Drinks="3">C</Type>
        <LowestAge>20</LowestAge>
        <MaxAge>49</MaxAge>
    </PersonSettings>
    <PersonSettings>
        <Type Drinks="5">A</Type>
        <Type Drinks="8">B</Type>
        <Type Drinks="1">C</Type>
        <LowestAge>50</LowestAge>
        <MaxAge>90</MaxAge>
    </PersonSettings>
    <Person Alive="Yes">
        <Type>A</Type>
        <Age>23</Age>
    </Person>
    <Person Alive="Yes">
        <Type>B</Type>
        <Age>50</Age>
    </Person>
    <Person Alive="Yes">
        <Type>C</Type>
        <Age>51</Age>
    </Person>
    <Person Alive="Yes">
        <Type>A</Type>
        <Age>70</Age>
    </Person>
</Root>
```

And the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <PersonsOneDrink>
        <xsl:value-of select="(count(/Root/Person[@Alive = 'Yes' and /Root/PersonSettings[**(Person/Age)** &gt;= LowestAge and **(Person/Age)** &lt;= MaxAge]/Type[. = **(Person/Type)** and @Drinks = '1']))"/>
    </PersonsOneDrink>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I want to do in this example is count the number of people with one drink, that are alive. I have different settings depending on the Type of Person and the Age of such person. For example Type A has one drink if between 20 and 49 years of age, while type C has one drink if between 50 to 90 years. The problem I find is that I cannot reference the outer node when going inside a second set of brackets. Is there any way to create a variable on the fly?

P.S: The parts with * * () * * are where I would like to reference the outer node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with a single `count()` expression, applied from the context of the root.

The problem here is that you need to refer to the values of `Person` within the predicate comparing them to the values of the prospective `PersonSettings`. For this, you need to use the [`current()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#misc-func) - but in order to have the `current()` function refer to `Person`, you must first make `Person` the context node.

Here is a suggested approach that writes a character for each `Person` that passes the test into a variable. This eliminates the need to convert the variable into a node-set before counting it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:variable name="v1">
        <xsl:for-each select="Person">
            <xsl:if test="@Alive = 'Yes' and /Root/PersonSettings[LowestAge &lt;= current()/Age and MaxAge >= current()/Age]/Type[. = current()/Type]/@Drinks = 1">
                <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <PersonsOneDrink>
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length($v1)"/>    
    </PersonsOneDrink>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PersonsOneDrink>2</PersonsOneDrink>
```

---

A more general solution - suitable if you want to perform several queries on the supplied data - would start by rewriting the input and assigning each `Person` the corresponding amount of drinks .

Here we will construct a variable that contains:

```
  <Person>
    <Type>A</Type>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Drinks>1</Drinks>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Type>B</Type>
    <Age>50</Age>
    <Drinks>8</Drinks>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Type>C</Type>
    <Age>51</Age>
    <Drinks>1</Drinks>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Type>A</Type>
    <Age>70</Age>
    <Drinks>5</Drinks>
  </Person>
```

Then, once the variable is converted into a node-set, it is trivial to get the number of persons with any amount of drinks:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="persons-rtf">
        <xsl:for-each select="Person">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <Drinks>
                    <xsl:value-of select="/Root/PersonSettings[LowestAge &lt;= current()/Age and MaxAge >= current()/Age]/Type[. = current()/Type]/@Drinks"/>
                </Drinks>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="persons" select="exsl:node-set($persons-rtf)/Person"/>
    <!-- output --> 
    <results>
        <PersonsOneDrink>
            <xsl:value-of select="count($persons[Drinks = 1])"/>
        </PersonsOneDrink>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, your suggestions are amazing and really useful, sadly in my requirements I cannot use node-set, but your first suggestion will do the trick :).

Comment: I am not aware of a XSLT 1.0 processor that does not support a `node-set()` function; it's really difficult to work without it.